# network unreachable for gcloud compute engine instance

Tags: firewall, ipv6, gcloud

I've just configured my first google cloud server with an ipv6 address.

When I try to run wget to the address it fails:

```
wget -6 https://[2600:1900:4180:bfa7:0:0:0:0]
--2024-03-04 18:20:39--  https://[2600:1900:4180:bfa7:0:0:0:0]/
Connecting to 2600:1900:4180:bfa7:0:0:0:0 (2600:1900:4180:bfa7:0:0:0:0)|2600:1900:4180:bfa7::|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

I have the following firewall rule in place:

[image]

Comment: Try to check the Network Tags of your VM instance and make sure that it has the same name as your target tags in the firewall. Are you also using ipv4 in your on premise network when you run wget command? You can also turn on the logs of your firewall to check what might causing the issue.

Comment: Where are you running `wget`? Does that system have IPv6 configured correctly? The error `Network is unreachable.` tells me that your network is not configured for IPv6. However, the IPv6 address does not look correct. Where did you get that address? Note: I doubt you have a VPC Firewall issue (at this point).

Comment: @JohnHanley you are correct about my home isp not supporting ipv6.  The v6 address is from a google cloud vm.

Answer (score 2):

As @john-hanley pointed out my home ISP doesn't support ipv6.

I never even thought this would be an issue, but on researching australian ISPs most still don't support v6.

Comment: This is also my point when I asked if you are using IPv4 in your network when you run the command since destination is IPv6.

Comment: It still is not too common in the US for home, depending on location. Mobile is typically ahead. The simple reason is not much demand. India is a better case, they have a strong demand and adoption rate. https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html